# Best way to extract repeating code part into a utility class?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I use some calculations via the `DisplayMetrics` in several of my Android Jetpack Composable screens:

```
activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(dm).let{
    ..//
}
```

As you can see it requires an `Activity` and I use that in several screens. Thats why I would like to extract that part into somewhere else and let make it use to every toher screen..

**What would be a nice pattern to do so?** Or how would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size one time only in MainActivity and just get the variable value like

```
(LocalContext.current as MainActivity).yourVariable
```

Or you can create a Kotlin File with a function which gets display sizes.

Or some views return match parent width and height so you can simply get it from there.

Or you can store this value in repository/viewmodel and get it from there.

Or create a custom @Composable function and use it everywhere:

```
@Composable
Activity.getMetrics(): YourSizes {}
```